# How to create a subtraction worksheet with random numbers in each question?

Tags: random-numbers, random

I would like to create a worksheet which looks like the following:

[image]

Here instead of manually typing every question, I would like to create random questions, where the subtrahend is from a set of integers (say {-10,-9,..,10}) and minuend is from another set of integers where the subtrahend may be greater than, equal to or smaller than the minuend.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the posting [How to create multipage tables of binary arithmetical problems (and associated answers) involving pseudo-random numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368643/5001) help?

Comment: Should there be exactly 5 rows and 5 columns per page?

Comment: @Mico, yes. It helps! Not necessarily 5 by 5; I am creating this for a small child and I would like to make the numbers bigger.

Comment: I use the `TiKz/PGF` package to do this kind of random exercices. It has a mathematic library that could help you. I can't do a full answer right now, I'll make one as soon as I can.

Comment: When I did this sort of thing, I used C++ to create the random problems and LaTeX to do the formatting.  That way I avoided questions like 0+0=?.  See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implementation using the `sagetex` package. It utilizes the open source computer algebra system, [SAGE](https://www.sagemath.org/), which is not part of the LaTeX distribution. This gives access to programming in Python as well.

```
\documentclass{article}%
% -----------------------------The preamble ------------------------------------
\usepackage{fix-cm}% allow for a bigger font
%  mathematical typesetting, fonts, and symbols
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% change the fonts
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}%  sets the margins
\usepackage{sagetex}%  use Sage for it's math ability
\pagestyle{empty} % remove the page numbers
% -----------------------------End of the preamble ------------------------------
\begin{document}
\fontsize{17pt}{20pt}\selectfont %sets font size
\noindent
\begin{sagesilent}
def Problems(rows,columns):
    output = r""
    output += r"\begin{tabular}{r"+"r"*(2*columns)+"}"
    for i in range(0,rows):
        minuend = [Integer(randint(5,25)) for i in range(0,columns)]
        subtrahend = [Integer(randint(-10,10)) for i in range(0,columns)]
        for j in range(0,columns):
            if j<columns-1:
                output += r"%s & \hspace{.2in} &"%(minuend[j])
            else:
                output += r"%s \\"%(minuend[j])
            ##### second row #####
        for j in range(0,columns):
            if j<columns-1:
                output += r"\underline{-  %s} & \hspace{.5in} &"%(subtrahend[j])
            else:
                output += r"\underline{-  %s}\\\\\\"%(subtrahend[j])

    output += r"\end{tabular}"

    return output

outputP = r""
outputP += Problems(4,5)
\end{sagesilent}
\begin{center}
\sagestr{outputP}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The output running in Cocalc is shown:
[image]

Some comments:

- output += r"\begin{tabular}{r"+"r"*(2*columns)+"}" uses Python to set the number of columns. Since there should be space between the problems, extra columns are added. Being able to adjust the columns used makes the `sagetex` approach very convenient.
- minuend = [Integer(randint(5,25)) for i in range(0,columns)] sets the minuend as a random integer between 5 and 25 while subtrahend = [Integer(randint(-10,10)) for i in range(0,columns)] values are set between -10 and 10.
- The fontsize has been increased to make the worksheet easier to read.
- outputP += Problems(4,5) results in the creation of 4 rows of 5 problems (20 problems). By adjusting these numbers you can easily change the number of problems in your worksheet.

The easiest way to work with `sagetex` is by opening a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation with `expl3`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,array}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\randomsubtractions}{mm}
 {% #1 = rows, #2 = columns
  \zuriel_randomsubtractions:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\boundsfirst}{mm}
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l_zuriel_first_lb_int { #1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_zuriel_first_ub_int { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\boundssecond}{mm}
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l_zuriel_second_lb_int { #1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_zuriel_second_ub_int { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_zuriel_first_lb_int
\int_new:N \l_zuriel_first_ub_int
\int_new:N \l_zuriel_second_lb_int
\int_new:N \l_zuriel_second_ub_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \zuriel_randomsubtractions:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} *{#2}{>{$}c<{$}} c @{\hspace{-\tabcolsep}} }
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \__zuriel_randomsubtraction_row:n { #2 } \\[6ex] }
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__zuriel_randomsubtraction_row:n
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \__zuriel_randomsubtraction: & }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__zuriel_randomsubtraction:
 {
  \begin{array}{@{} r @{}}
  \int_rand:nn { \l_zuriel_first_lb_int } { \l_zuriel_first_ub_int } \\
  - \int_rand:nn { \l_zuriel_second_lb_int } { \l_zuriel_second_ub_int } \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\boundsfirst{-10}{10} \boundssecond{1}{10}

\randomsubtractions{5}{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]